# How can I store Android app data?

Tags: java, android, csv, export-to-csv

I have developed one android application in which I used **intent class** and merge four applications:

1. 'Get coordinate with x-y' this application is ontouchactivity application
2. 'Wi-Fi scanner'
3. QR code scanner
4. 'camera'

I want to store the results of all four applications in one **.CSV** format. I am facing some problems to write the Java code.

Can I write code in main Java file or do I have to make another class for that?

Please give me a suggestion.

Comment: What problems have you faced? What have you tried exactly?

Comment: what are you considering the main java file, is it the main activity class? Creating another class to store data into a .csv format is simply a design decision.. You could create a helper class that you would call whenever you want to store the data in a .csv file.